# Structured data for social media profile doesn't show up under "Rich Cards"

Tags: google-search-console, knowledge-graph, rich-cards

I'm trying to use rich cards to get Google to show my social media profiles in its "knowledge panel".

I've followed Google's instructions for doing this but I can't get it to work. In Search Console the data I've used shows up under Structured Data and shows no errors, but doesn't show up under Rich Cards.

The code I've used:

[image]

Comment: It might not be relevant for this problem, but in general: Please always include markup as actual code, not as image.

Comment: I did initially try to do that but as a newby my post wasn't allowed to contain more than 2 URLs, hence the image workaround.

Comment: I can’t test it, but I *think* the editor ignores this rule if you use code markup (indenting each line with four spaces; you can mark the whole code block and press Ctrl+k to get this done automatically).

Answer (score 1):

Two things here:

First, like Rich Snippets, Rich Cards aren't guaranteed even if your code is perfect. Moreover, Rich Cards were only [launched globally in May 2016](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2016/05/introducing-rich-cards.html), and then only for recipe- and movie-related content returned in google.com.

> We’re starting to show rich cards for two content categories: recipes
>   and movies. They will appear initially on mobile search results in
>   English for google.com. We’re actively experimenting with more
>   opportunities to provide more publishers with a rich preview of their
>   content.

Second, and more pertinent to what I think you're after, Knowledge Graph [is something different](https://www.google.com/intl/es419/insidesearch/features/search/knowledge.html) from Rich Snippets and Rich Cards. It's the panel at the right of search results which displays entity information, usually (but not always) derived from Wikipedia and Wikidata information.

If you're not already getting a Knowledge Graph panel for your entity, you won't get the social profile links either. The latter is contingent on the former.

Getting a Knowledge Graph result isn't always easy without having a Wikipedia article, which can mean you're subject to Wikipedia's definition of notability and the whims of its editors, but there are various articles around the web on achieving a Knowledge Graph result *without* a Wikipedia article.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do already have a knowledge graph result which you can see here: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=van+od

And I've followed Google's how-to on how to achieve this which suggests it's now a standard part of what you can use the spec for:
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/social-profile-links

Comment: @RobinS That's a local business result, not Knowledge Graph.

Answer (score 0):

The source code for the main webpage has **[FATAL Error](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?showoutline=yes&doc=http%3A%2F%2Fvanod.co.uk%2F)**. Note that on this error the scanner stops and does not scan further. This markup should be closely tied to the content of the web page. Therefore, source code errors prevent scanners from correctly reading and understanding markup with structured data. Further, Google's answer about the errors of the source code:

> > This came up recently with the change of the guidelines, with regards to 
> >     change made in the webmaster guidelines. We mentioned use valid HTML. The 
> >     question here is Is the W3C Validation (Broken HTML) ranking factor or 
> >     should we care about it?
>
> It is *not directly* a ranking factor. It is not the sense that if your
>   site is not using valid HTML we will remove it from he index. Because I 
>   think we will have a pretty empty search results.
>
> But there are a few aspects there that do come into play. On the one hand, 
>   a site with really broken HTML, something that we see really rarely, *then 
>   it is really hard for us to crawl it and index the content because we can’t
>   pick it up.*
>
> The other two aspects which are kind more in regards *to structured data*. 
>   Sometimes it is really hard to pick up the structured data when the HTML is
>   broken completely. So you can’t easily use a validator for the structured 
>   data.
>
> The other thing is in regards *to mobile devices and cross browser support 
>   is if you have broken HTML then that sometimes really hard to render on 
>   newer devices*.

Additionally, read **[Introduction to Structured Data](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data)** + **[Build, Test, and Release Your Structured Data of Google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/prototype)**. Check the source code of your web pages on the **[Nu Html Checker](https://validator.w3.org/nu/)**. Check the markup of the structured data of your web pages on the **[Structure Data Tester of Google](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool)**. 
An SEO asked Google's John Mueller why his rich cards (rich snippets) aren't showing up in search. John responded with three possible reasons over **[Twitter](https://twitter.com/JohnMu/status/895992952262017025)**:

- Technically incorrect (use SDTT)
- Not compliant with policies (eg, wrong markup type)
- Or general quality issue with site

**[Source](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-rich-snippets-arent-showing-in-search-24312.html)**

Comment: Thanks for flagging this up, looks like I have a few things to fix. I had used the Structured Data test tool you've linked to and it parsed fine, and the same result is shown in Search Console under structured data, which is why it's confusing as it seems there's nothing wrong with my syntax so the problem must be something else.

Comment: If you have waited at least one week since your marked-up page was last crawled by Google, report the missing events using the small "Feedback" link under the Knowledge Graph panel in Google search. Click "Wrong?" on your company's name and explain the problem, being sure to use the term "social profiles" in your description of the problem.